# sending bulk emails using sendEmail action in flow

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, workflow, singleemailmessage

I have been lately exploring on how to send bulk emails from flow. There is documented way to send single email using singleEmail action as described [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_actions_sendemail.htm&type=5). I implemented this and new I can successfully convert

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage semail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
/*some awesome code*/   
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {semail});
```

to

```
Map<String, Object> flowVariables = new Map<String, Object>{
                'body' => htmlBody,
                'toAddresses' => toAddresses,
\*some more keys as required by sendEmail action*\                    
            };

Flow.Interview.SendEmail sendEmail = new Flow.Interview.SendEmail(params);
sendEmail.start();
```

[image]

However I wanted to send bulk emails i.e., I wanted to convert this

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
for(/*some iteration*/){
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage semail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    /*some awesome code*/
    emails.add(semail );
}
 Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
```

to

```
List<Map<String, Object>> bulkParams= new List<Map<String, Object>>;
for(/*some iteration*/){
    

    Map<String, Object> flowVariables = new Map<String, Object>{
                    'body' => htmlBody,
                    'toAddresses' => toAddresses,
        \*some more keys as required by sendEmail action*\
        }
    bulkParams.add(flowVariables );
};
```

The approach I was using was to directly invoke the flow inside loop which I am very doubtful if its a good practice as shown

```
for(/*some iteration*/){    
    Map<String, Object> flowVariables = new Map<String, Object>{
                    'body' => htmlBody,
                    'toAddresses' => toAddresses,
        \*some more keys as required by sendEmail action*\
        }
    Flow.Interview.SendEmail sendEmail = new Flow.Interview.SendEmail(bulkParams);
    sendEmail.start();
};
```

Also adding to that I had few more doubts, the [document](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_actions_sendemail.htm&type=5) mentions followinf for email recipients

> For the email to send successfully, enter a value for Email Addresses (comma-separated) or Email Addresses (collection). You can use both parameters as long as the combined number of email addresses is five or fewer. This parameter accepts single-value resources of any type. That value is treated as text.

So if we provide email addresses of internal users, it would count in SingleEmail against the limit?

Comment: same body is sent to _n_ emails? or is calling context going to send body0 to emails (a,b,c); body1 to emails (d,e,f)?

Comment: @cropredy the body can vary between email addresses

Answer (score 1):

Several things going on here

Given that you asserted in the comments that within a transaction that  *body0* could apply to emails `a@example.com`, `b.example.com` but *body1* could apply to emails `c@example.com, d@example.com, e.example.com`

Then:

You will need to call the `Flow.Interview` `start()` method for each unique *bodyX* within the transaction

To address the 5 emails per Flow `Send Email` action limit you have two choices

- Change your calling program to ensure that at most 5 emails are sent per *bodyX*, potentially calling the `Flow.Interview` `start()` method more than once for a single *bodyX* (e.g. if you have 6 emails for *bodyX*, then first call to `start()` provides 5 emails and second call to start() provides the 6th email
- Don't use the Send Email action but instead use the [UnofficialSF.com Send Better Email Flow Action](https://unofficialsf.com/send-better-email-flow-action/). This doesn't have these limits as it uses Apex to send the emails

As for limits, consult the [Email Limits guide](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.allocations_email_general.htm&type=5)

> Each licensed org can send single emails to a maximum of 5,000 external email addresses, or recipients, per day. A day is based on Greenwich Mean Time (GMT).
>
> Sending emails to internal email recipients doesn't count toward the org daily limit.
>
> For orgs created before Spring ’19, the org daily limit is enforced only for emails sent via Apex and Salesforce APIs, except for REST API.
>
> For orgs created in Spring ’19 and later, the org daily limit is also enforced for email alerts, simple email actions, Send Email actions in flows, and REST API.

Comment: Okay , So  you basically mean Apex is Better than Flow? Since it offers more flexibility. Is there any good reason to use flow? @cropredy

Comment: I didn't say that; you can use Flow; just that the if your data has > 5 emails per Flow Interview, adjust your caller to make sure that each Interview has no more than 5 emails. I presumed the Flow has other functions besides sending emails (either now or in the future).